# c# jpeg compression with trackbar

Tags: c#, compression, jpeg

I need to compress a jpeg file, and the compression rate must be dynamic, set by a track bar. I'm using C#, Windows Forms. I think variable jpgcompression just needs to be of type "Encoder" or something like that, but am unsure of how to do this. Keep getting: "Para meter is not valid" error message when using type string or integer. My code is below:

```
public void resizeImage(Image newImg, int width, int height, string filePath, int jpgCompression)
    {
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(newImg, width, height);
        ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        var jpgcompression = jpgCompression.ToString() + "L";
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, jpgcompression);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        newImage.Save(filePath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: C# is a case-sensitive language, `jpgcompression` does not use the `jpgCompression` method argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value as a long and check to make sure you're passing a value between 0 (max compression) and 100 (max quality, no compression).

If you are, check the exception to make sure that it's the encoderparam that has the issue.